# Any way to map functions with more than one argument in Scheme/Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm currently doing an introductory course in Racket/Scheme, and am currently studying map, apply, and fold. For the most part, I've been assuming that map can only work on lambdas that accept a single argument. However, for certain problems I would find it incredibly useful to get around this somewhat - say, having a function that can be mapped to a list whilst also carrying an accumulator that updates independently for each recursive function call. While I can't get much more specific than that for fear of violating Honor Code, is there any way to get around being unable to give each recursive call an accumulator if you plan to use map?

Answer (score 4):

`map` takes as many lists as you want:

```
(map + '(1 2 3) '(3 2 1) '(3 3 3)) ; ==> (7 7 7)
```

`fold` has an accumulator:

```
(foldl (lambda (a b c acc) (+ a b c acc)) 1 '(1 2 3) '(3 2 1) '(3 3 3)) ; ==> 22
```